# Clean/Disable forms history

Tags: jquery, html, django, forms

I am building my chat app using Django and AJAX.

How d I disable the form history popping up while typing in a message?

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Answer (score 1):

You can set the input box's [autocomplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486(VS.85).aspx) property to off.